# Accessing inner ordered dictionaries returned by simple-salesforce

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am working with simple-salesforce to query salesforce via Python. My query returns an ordereddict in the following format

```
OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1), ('done', True), ('records', [OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Case'), ('url', 'www.blah.com')])), ('Number', '6904'), ('Severity', 'P1'), ('Product__c', 'd231'), ('Status', 'Available'), ('Case_Comments__r', OrderedDict([('totalSize', 1), ('done', True), ('records', [OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Comment__c'), ('url', 'www.blah.com')])), ('CreatedDate', '2019-11-05T12:10:06.000+0000'), ('Text__c', 'dummy text'), ('Created_By_Name', 'TEST USER')])])]))])])])
```

I want to pull out specific data but I am having issues accessing the inner ordered dict. For example I can get 'Number' and 'Severity' by doing the following

```
list1 = [(record['Number'], record['Severity']) for record in data['records']]
```

But I also need to access 'Comment_c', i've tried the below but its failing.

```
list1 = [(record['Number'], record['Severity'], record['Case_Comments__r']['records']['Text__c']) for record in data['records']]
```

It fails with "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: "but its failing" is not a proper problem description. Is there an error message? Does your computer crash?

Comment: updated with error details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, `record['Case_Comments__r']['records']` is a list of `OrderedDict`s:

```
('records', [OrderedDict(...), ...])
```

So it's not possible to index this list with a string like `record['Case_Comments__r']['records']['Text__c']` - you'll need to loop over the list and extract data from each `OrderedDict`:

```
..., record['Severity'], [comment['Text__c'] for comment in record['Case_Comments__r']['records']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to parse OrderedDict's from `simple-salesforce` query results, which allows you to set defaults in the event that what you're searching for is `None`.

```py
def get_field_data_from_salesforce_object(sf_session, field, default="some_default"):
    field_query = f"Select {field} FROM Case WHERE Id = 'some-id'"
    field_data = sf_session.query(field_query)

    for k, v in field_data.items():
        if k == "records":
            for item in v:
                field_key = item.get(field)

                if field_key is None:
                    if default is not None:
                        field_key = default
                    else:
                        field_key = "(Not provided)"
    return field_key
```